# images are not uploading into FTP files while using PHP cmds

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, ftp

I have tried files upload to server using ftp connection in php and its not working, its connecting and and telling uploaded successfully but no image will be upload in the directories....i have tried following code please help by correcting it

image.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_1" type="file" /><br />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_2" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "XXXXXX";
$ftp_username   = "XXXXX";
$ftp_password   =  "XXXX";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "connected as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
  }
else {
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}
$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["name"];
$file2 = $_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["name"];

$remote_file_path = "/imagetest/123/".$file;
$remote_file_path2 = "/imagetest/123/".$file2;

ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path2, $_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";
?>
```

Comment: the path should be...

$remote_file_path = "./imagetest/123/".$file;

Comment: You also need to use ftp_put in binary mode for images

Comment: @Jayakarthik Appasamy Not working then also,...

Comment: @Mark Baker How to use ftp_put in binary mode,...

Comment: Reading the documentation for [ftp_put()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) you should realise that the constant `FTP_ASCII` is setting ASCII mode, and the corresponding `FTP_BINARY` will set binary mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try..

```
$remote_file_path = "./imagetest/123/".$file;
```

or simply...

```
$remote_file_path = "imagetest/123/".$file;
```

try this...

```
$uploaddir = "./temp/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"]` is just a string with temporary file name(such as 'aaaaa.jpg' but not '/tmp/upload/aaa.jpg'). You should use `move_uploaded_file` to move files uploaded with a form since `$_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"]` doesn't contain the actual file path.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Since I haven't experience to move uploaded file directly to another server, here's what will work, I suppose. 
1.First move the uploaded file to a local folder.

```
$localPath = '/xxxx/upload/' //confirm your web server user have the right to write in this folder
$tmp_name = $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"] // confirm you got a filename here.
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$localPath/$tmp_name"); // You should have a new file in /xxxx/upload/
```

in your webserver.

2.Then move the file from local folder to remote server.

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, "$localPath/$tmp_name" ,FTP_ASCII);// If this goes wrong, you should test this with a local file created mannually and upload it to your remote server. If it fails, there must be something wrong in your remote connection or permission.
```

3.Then delete the file in local folder.

```
unlink("$localPath/$tmp_name");// The file in local host should be deleted.
```

Please give it a shot.

Comment: `bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination ) `how to replace with this `ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);`

Comment: @Redsun unfortunately I have no experience to move uploaded file directly to another but here's what will work I think. First move the uploaded file to a local folder. Then move the file from local folder to remote server. Then delete the file in local folder. I'm editing my answer now and you should see the change in several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure paths of the files are fine (syntactically and are actually pointing to the file initended) and secondly, the `ftp_put` function returns a `boolean`. You could check it's value to see if the upload is happening successfully or not.

I think another problem in this case might also be that the server's firewall is hindering establishing a data channel between the client (i.e you) and the server. Try turning the `passive mode` on before uploading files. Just add the following line before `ftp_put` and see if it works:

```
 // turn passive mode on
 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

 $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

You will also have to use Binary mode for images as rightly pointed out.

[Relevant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php). Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: You're sure that you can connect to the ftp server? Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: i think something wrong here `$_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"]`

Comment: @Redsun, just make sure the file paths are correct and that you're using `binary` mode for images like I've updated in the answer and try it again.